# What does this cast do?

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

I was taking a look at some code for a microcontroller when I came across this cast:
`(void (*) (void))ROM_FPUTABLE[8]`
I was wondering what it actually does. Any ideas?

Comment: It casts a function pointer to a particular function prototype.

Comment: Alright, how did you reach this conclusion? p.s.: wouldn't it be clearer then if it was written (void* (void))? or is this a different cast?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

Comment: `void (*) (void)` is obviously pointer to function returning nothing and having no parameters. BTW: You left out the closing brace at the end of your expression.

Comment: Try it at [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: Nevermind my first comment. This can get somewhat confusing, though.

Comment: It's simple if you understand it ;-)

Comment: For the question in your comment: This would be a function (expecting no arguments) returning a pointer to `void`; which is invalid in a cast expression, as you can't cast to function types (but to function pointer types, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void (*) (void)` specifies a pointer to a function, which returns nothing, and takes no arguments.

Therefore `(void (*) (void))` casts something to a pointer to a function, which returns nothing, and takes no arguments.